# Random Walk - Solving $P(x,y)=P(a,y)P(x-a,y+a)$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, functions, probability-distributions, random-walk

How can I find any/all function which satisfies $P(x,y)=P(a,y)P(x-a,y+a)$ for all $x>a>0$?

$P(x,y)$ is the probability that a random walk on the real line starting at 0 reaches -x before reaching y. So we also have $P(cx,cy)=P(x,y)$

By dividing it up into infinitesimal intervals I might be able to solve it if I could find the limit of $(c^2/m)^m Pochhammer[1 + m/c^2, m]$ as m goes to infinity, but mathematica coouldnt tackle it.

How do we obtain P(x,y)?

Comment: What distribution functions are you familiar with?

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Well, a solution is $P(x,y)=y/(x+y)$, obviously.

Comment: And $$(c^2/m)^m(1+m/c^2)_m\sim(1+c^2)^{3/2}a^m$$ with $$a=(1+c^2)^{1+1/c^2}e^{-1}$$

Comment: @Did Allright man, my approach doesnt work, got any better idea?

Comment: Every solution is such that $P(x,y)=P(1,y)P(1,y+1)\cdots P(1,y+x-1)$, hence $P(x,y)=g(x+y)/g(y)$ with $g(x)=\prod\limits_{z=2}^{x}P(1,z-1)$ for every positive $x$ and, conversely, $P(x,y)=g(x+y)/g(y)$ solves this for every (nonzero) $g$.

Comment: @Did I am trying to find P(x,y) for a random walk as defined in second paragraph

Comment: And for the random walk with symmetric $\pm1$ steps or for the Brownian motion, it is well known that $P(x,y)=y/(x+y)$. Is this your question?

Comment: Yea, cool awesome, thanks